# Convert input text to cyrillic on keypress

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am working in Asp.Net C#, on converting typed letters into textbox, to automatically be changed in cyrillic. If i type "B" should be displayed "Б"... I've made it on textchanged with autoPostBack:

```
string str = char.ConvertFromUtf32(66);
str = "Б";
txtBox.Text = str;
```

But is it possible for live converting immediately after entering the letter.

Comment: You have to do it in client-side JavaScript then

Comment: You'd have to convert your code to JScript and do client-side.  Also you may be underthinking the approach a bit if you're doing it letter by letter since some Cyrillic letters won't map 1:1.  E.g. `ya` transliteration for `Я` is two letters.  Look at behavior of `translate.google.com`'s virtual keyboard to see that it's more involved then direct letter mapping.